# Jpa returns more than one result although only one row is in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am running different JPA queries in the form of

```java
Float getDepositVolumeByDepositIdDepositAndSpeciesIdSpeciesAndRangeIdRangeAndSubRangeIdSubrange(Long idDeposit, Long idSpecies, Long idRange, Long idSubRange); // this is one of the methods that fail
@Query("select stock.depositVolume from Stock s where s.deposit.idDeposit = ?1 and s.species.idSpecies = ?2 and s.range.idRange = ?3 and s.subrange.idSubrange = ?4")
Float getVolumeByDepositIdDepositAndSpeciesIdSpeciesAndRangeIdRangeAndSubRangeIdSubrange(Long idDeposit, Long idSpecies, Long idRange, Long idSubRange); // this one is just for ilustrative purpose and throws the exact same error
```

These two queries being just some of those that should return one row. Although the database has only one row corresponding to the data provided to the query, hibernate throws the following error message:

> Result returns more than one elements

I have turned on hibernate query log and the query generated is the following for the first method:

```
select stock0_volume_stock as col_0_0_ from public.stock stock0_ where stock0_.id_deposit = ? and stock0_.id_species = ? and stock0_.id_range = ? and stock0_.id_sub_range = ?
```

with the correctly bound parameters. I ran the query on PostGres and it returns only one row with a `float`.

It is worth mentioning that my class declaration is:

```
public interface StockRepository extends QueryDslPredicateExecutro<Stock>, JpaRepository<Stock, long>
```

What I have ended doing is change those methods into

```java
List<Stock> findFirstByDepositIdDepositAndSpeciesIdSpeciesAndRangeIdRangeAndSubRangeIdSubrange(Long idDeposit, Long idSpecies, Long idRange, Long idSubRange); // now it justly returns only one row, the first one
```

I usually suppose, and certainly on previous projects this was the behavior observed, that the first method should map **the only result fetched from the database** into the expected `float`

I am very interested what is the explanation of this behaviour.